# iOS asset catalog for background image without cropping or stretching

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode6, assets

I know this has been asked before but the questions are older and done in code. I'm wondering if their are any updates for best practice and keeping the target 8+.

My issue is I'm not sure how to use the asset catalog for full size backgrounds without cropping or stretching at 2x since the devices aren't the same size. I've seen ways in code but this seems to be an issue that the asset catalog should take care of especially with the asset catalog compiling out unused sizes in the next xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the assets catalog you have to load the correct images (at correct resolutions) for both 1x 2x and, since iPhone 6+, 3x. Then, if u hit device specific, you can upload your iphone5 background picture (+568) & so on. After you load everything you should use either an UIImageView with specific Constraints (!!!) either backgroundColor:

```
yourview.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "<assetName>")!)
```